# serialize() is giving empty value in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have tried several ways to get the serialize data from serialize() method in controller but in controller all the inputs are showing null values.

I have used razor views so that id and name will appear automatically.

Here is my javascript code..

```
$("#save-btn").click(function () {
        debugger;
        console.log($("supplierForm").serialize());
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/AddRecords",
                cache: false,
                data: $("#FrmGrid_rowed3").serialize(),
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.Success)
                    {                     
                        $('#formdivId').css('display', 'none');
                        $('#footerId').css('margin-top', 205);
                        $('#fbox_rowed3_reset').css('height', 28);
                        $('#fbox_rowed3_search').css('height', 30);
                        LoadJqGrid();
                        $('.spanCss').text("");
                        $('.inputCss').val("");
                        $('.ui-jqgrid-headlink.ui-icon.ui-icon-circle-triangle-n').hide();
                        alert(response.Response);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('alert-msg').text(response.Response);
                    }
                }
            });
          //}
        });
```

And this is my controller code...

```
 [HttpPost]
       [ValidateCustomAntiForgeryToken]
        public JsonResult AddRecords(SupplierModel supplier)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Repository repo = new Repository();
                string result = repo.AddorEditData(supplier);
                if (result != "")
                {
                    return Json(new { Success = true, Response = result });
                }
                return Json(new { Success = true, Response = result });
            }           
            else
            {
                return Json(new {Success = false , Response = "Please Fill All the Fields"});
            }

        }
```

And this is the code for razor view

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("AddRecords","Home",FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "FrmGrid_rowed3", @class = "form-horizontal", style = "padding-top:25px" }))
                  {
                      @*<form id="FrmGrid_rowed3" name="supplierForm" class="form-horizontal" style = "padding-top:25px">*@
                       @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                                <div class="row rowCss">
                                  <div class="col-sm-6" >
                                     <div class="form-group">              
                                        <div class="col-sm-2 labelCss" style="margin-left: 25px;">
                                             <label class="control-label">Company Name:</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-4 inputCss" style="height:40px">
                                             @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.supplierID)
                                             @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.companyName, new { @class="form-control inputCss" , placeholder = "Enter Company Name" }) 
                                             <div style="width:254px">  
                                                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.companyName,"",new{@class="spanCss" , @id="compName"}) 
                                             </div>
                                        </div>     
                                      </div>           
                                 </div>


                                 <div class="col-sm-6 "> 
                                      <div class="form-group">                 
                                        <div class="col-sm-2 labelCss" style="margin-left:-58px"> 
                                             <label class="control-label">Contact Title:</label>
                                         </div>
                                         <div class="col-sm-4 inputCss" style="height:40px">
                                             @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.contactTitle, new { @class="form-control inputCss" , placeholder = "Enter Contact Name" })                          <span class="spanCss"></span>
                                             <div style="width:254px">  
                                                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.contactTitle,"",new{@class="spanCss" , @id="contTitle"}) 
                                             </div>
                                         </div> 
                                      </div>              
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                            <div class="row rowCss">
                                 <div class="col-sm-6" style="margin-right:1px">
                                     <div class="form-group">              
                                        <div class="col-sm-2 labelCss">
                                             <label class="control-label">Contact Name:</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-4 inputCss" style="height:40px"> 
                                             @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.contactName, new { @class="form-control inputCss" , placeholder = "Enter Contact Title" })
                                             <div style="width:254px">  
                                                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.contactName,"",new{@class="spanCss" , @id="contName"}) 
                                             </div> 
                                        </div>     
                                      </div>           
                                 </div>


                                 <div class="col-sm-6" style="margin-right:-1px"> 
                                      <div class="form-group">                 
                                        <div class="col-sm-2 labelCss" style="margin-left:-57px"> 
                                             <label class="control-label">Address:</label>
                                         </div>
                                         <div class="col-sm-4 inputCss" style="margin-top:-5px" style="height:40px">
                                               @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.address,2,5, new { @class="form-control inputCss" , placeholder = "Enter Address",style="height:45px" })
                                             <div style="width:254px">  
                                                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.address,"",new{@class="spanCss" , @id="Address"}) 
                                             </div>
                                        </div> 
                                       </div>              
                                 </div>
                               </div>
                            <div class="row rowCss">
                                 <div class="col-sm-6">
                                     <div class="form-group">              
                                        <div class="col-sm-2 labelCss">
                                             <label class="control-label">City:</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-4 inputCss" style="height:40px">
                                               @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.city, new { @class="form-control inputCss" , placeholder = "Enter City Name" })
                                              <div style="width:254px">  
                                                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.city,"",new{@class="spanCss" , @id="City"}) 
                                             </div>
                                        </div>     
                                      </div>           
                                 </div>

                                 <div class="col-sm-6"> 
                                      <div class="form-group">                 
                                        <div class="col-sm-2 labelCss" style="margin-left:-56px"> 
                                             <label class="control-label">Region:</label>
                                         </div>
                                         <div class="col-sm-4 inputCss" style="height:40px">
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.region, new { @class="form-control inputCss" , placeholder = "Enter Region" })
                                             <div style="width:254px">  
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.region,"",new{@class="spanCss" , @id="Region"}) 
                                             </div>
                                        </div> 
                                       </div>              
                                 </div>
                                </div>
                            <div class="row rowCss">
                                 <div class="col-sm-6" style="margin-right:1px">
                                     <div class="form-group">              
                                        <div class="col-sm-2 labelCss">
                                             <label class="control-label">Postal Code:</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-4 inputCss" style="height:40px">
                                               @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.postalCode, new { @class="form-control inputCss" , placeholder = "Enter Postal Code" })
                                            <div style="width:254px">
                                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.postalCode,"",new{@class="spanCss" , @id="PostalCode" ,style="width:200px" }) 
                                            </div>   
                                        </div>     
                                      </div>           
                                   </div>

                                  <div class="col-sm-6" style="margin-right:-1px"> 
                                      <div class="form-group" >                 
                                        <div class="col-sm-2 labelCss" style="margin-left:-55px"> 
                                             <label class="control-label">Country:</label>
                                         </div>
                                         <div class="col-sm-4 inputCss" style="height:40px">
                                               @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.country, new { @class="form-control inputCss" , placeholder = "Enter Country" ,style="width:280px" })
                                               <div style="width:254px">  
                                                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.country,"",new{@class="spanCss" , @id="Country"}) 
                                             </div>
                                        </div> 
                                       </div>              
                                 </div>
                             </div>
                            <div class="row rowCss">
                                 <div class="col-sm-6">
                                     <div class="form-group">              
                                        <div class="col-sm-2 labelCss">
                                             <label class="control-label">Phone:</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-4 inputCss" style="height:40px">
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.phone, new { @class="form-control inputCss" , placeholder = "Enter Phone Number" })
                                           <div style="width:254px">  
                                                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.phone,"",new{@class="spanCss" , @id="Phone"}) 
                                             </div>
                                        </div>     
                                      </div>           
                                   </div>

                                  <div class="col-sm-6" style="margin-left:-54px"> 
                                      <div class="form-group">                 
                                        <div class="col-sm-2 labelCss" style="margin-left:0px" > 
                                             <label class="control-label">Fax:</label>
                                         </div>
                                         <div class="col-sm-4 inputCss" style="height:40px">
                                                 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.fax, new { @class="form-control inputCss" , placeholder = "Enter Fax Number" })
                                                 <div style="width:254px">  
                                                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.fax,"",new{@class="spanCss" , @id="Fax"}) 
                                             </div>
                                        </div> 
                                       </div>              
                                 </div>
                             </div>
                            <div class="row rowCss" style="height:24px">
                                <center>
                                    <input id="save-btn" type="button"  value="Submit" />
                                    <input type="button" value="Cancel" id="cData"  />
                                </center>
                            </div>
                  }
```

Please suggest any solution as i have tried all the ways to get that data in my cotroller.

Comment: Show you model. Does it contain properties (or just fields)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734494/pass-serialized-form-to-action-and-bind-to-model), you should send proper JSON data to you controller.

```
data: JSON.stringify({supplier: $("#FrmGrid_rowed3").serialize()}),
```

and also add

```
contentType: 'application/json',
```

to your AJAX call.

Comment: Yes, I think JSON.stringify is what's missing here, but the action method having "supplier" as it's name has no significance in the JSON that needs to be passed back to the server.

Comment: @BrianMains Really? I thought that data binder recognizes what data he should be working on, based on arguments name and what came in request. I mean, that if I had method `Something(string action)` it would not work, when I would pass some value not being named _action_. Or maybe I just didn't understand what you said - either way please explain where I'm being wrong :-)

Comment: A standard form post would not need a reference to supplier; otherwise, all of the input fields would have to be prefixed with "supplier_".  The mechanism is the same for AJAX posts, and I believe it needs to interpret the root level properties, because it's mapping "ID" on the root level object to SuppliersModel.ID, and so on.  Maybe I'm wrong... at this point, the easiest way to verify is to try :-)

Comment: You **do not** need to stringify the data and use `contentType: 'application/json',` OP's code in the ajax is correct.